# laravel shows 404 error upload to my domain

Tags: php, laravel

when i upload my domain it shows my home page but i goto other pages it shows me 404 error url not working. but my localhost site working well. how i fix this error.

this is my route list

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});


Route::resource('/computer', 'CategoriesController');

Route::resource('/cctv', 'CctvsController');

Route::get('/results', function(){

    $computers = \App\Computer::where('item_name', 'like', '%' . request('query') . '%')->get();

    $cctvs = \App\Cctv::where('item_name', 'like', '%' . request('query') . '%')->get();

    return view('computer.view')->with('computers', $computers)
                                        ->with('cctvs', $cctvs)
                                        ->with('item_name', 'Search Results : ' . request('query'))
                                        ->with('category_id', \App\Comproduct::take(8)->get())
                                        ->with('category_id', \App\Cctvproduct::take(8)->get())
                                        ->with('query', request('query'));
});


Route::get('/cctv', function(){

    return view('cctv.index');
});

Route::get('/contact', function(){

    return view('contact');
});


Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();
});

Route::post('/contact/submit', 'MessagesController@submit');

Route::post('/cctv/submit', 'QuotesController@submit');
```

Comment: That sounds like the webserver hasn't been set up to handle routes. See here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation#web-server-configuration

Comment: this error occurs for not adding .htaccess file into cpanel. now i fix my problem